# jQuery - what is the feature of this selector rule?

Tags: jquery

I saw the following usage of jQuery selector:

```
$('[value=""]', event.target).remove();
```

I can guess the meaning of this statement is to remove the option value="" from the selector event.target.

The pattern looks like $(A, B).
What kind of selector rule is used here in jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: Incidentally you should generally avoid the `value` attribute in attribute selectors. It should select elements by the contents of their `value=""` attribute in the document (the initial value), not by the DOM Level 1 HTML `.value` property (the current value). However due to various bugs it *sometimes* doesn't do that in jQuery, potentially giving you weird cross-browser problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

This code passes the `context` parameter, meaning that it will search only the children of the second parameter.
It's equivalent to `$(event.target).find('[value=""]')`

Comment: Yep, and I'd typically write it with the `find()` method in preference. It's clearer about what's happening. The `$()` function is already terribly overloaded, let's avoid sticking more stuff in it!

Answer (score 1):

That snippet will remove all the elements which have the empty attribute value, descendants of the event.target element.

Example, removing all the links on the stackoverflow listing page:

```
jQuery('a', jQuery('#question-mini-list')).remove()
```